# React Route Redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read all possible thread about programmatically redirection in React but I couldn't make it working.

My code looks like this (I removed as much  I could to make it shorter):

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import {Login} from "./login/Login";

class App extends React.Component {
  login(loginResponse) {
    ...
    # Here I want to redirect but it does not work
    this.props.history.push('/some-path/');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <div id="content">
            <Messages />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Welcome} />
              ...
              <Route path="/portal/login" render={() => <Login sendMessage={this.sendMessage} />} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

I'd like to redirect when the login method is called to a different path.
With `this.props.history.push('/some-path/');` I get `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.

In most of the places I read about `withRouter` but I could not make it work.

What am I missing to get the `history`?
Or what's the easiest to make the redirect work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where are you actually calling your login function?

Comment: Does you App have history prop? Have you used withRouter on your App? I think no. You can try withRouter but I don't know how suitable is using it in main App like that. Why don't you use Redirect from react-router-dom? I'm not a pro but I'm using Redirect on my Login page. After a successful login page redirects to the desired url.

Comment: App is a parent of Router so even withRouter wouldn't work in this exact configuration since context isn't available on the parent. <Redirect /> Component is a good suggestion, but also any child of <Route> gets history on props.. would need to see where login is meant to be called to give a specific answer

Comment: I removed the call to `login` as I thought it wasn't relevant for this.

I tried to use `withRouter` but it looks it cannot be used on main app because nothing was starting up.

How would I use the <Redirect> programmatically? I tried to render it but again it did not work.

Comment: I tried to as well to pass `history` to the `Login` component and actually that worked. I really wanted to have the redirect from here... but I guess I could do in a subcomponent if it's not possible to use history on the main one.

Comment: you could do it on the main one. you're passing `loginResponse` as a function argument to `login` you could do the same with `history`

Comment: I cannot easily pass `history` to the `login` function as it is from a callback and I don't have a reference to `history` in the first place from the main app. The question is how can I get a reference to the history here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the main problem here is that I was trying to implement the redirect on the top level component.

I ended up moving a bit of login around and do the redirect from the `Login` component that is rendered thanks to the `Route` component therefore can access the `history`.

This is the code I used:

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import {Login} from "./login/Login";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <div id="content">
            <Messages />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Welcome} />
              ...
              <Route path="/portal/login" render={(router) => <Login router={router} sendMessage={this.sendMessage} />} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onLoginResponse = this.onLoginResponse.bind(this);
  }

  onLoginResponse(loginResponse) {
    ...
    this.props.router.history.push('/portal/');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="login-form">
        Login page ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The nice thing of this is that now the code for handling a login response is in the Login page.
But as I wanted to store the user who logged in into the main app status I needed to do some extra work.